# Can't find FinishMonsterBuffer() method

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I created a table following the flatbuffers [tutorial](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__cpp_usage.html) and compiled it to C++ code. Say, its name is Doc.

In the tutorial, it is said:

> Regardless of whether you used CreateMonster or MonsterBuilder, you
>   now have an offset to the root of your data, and you can finish the
>   buffer using:
>
> FinishMonsterBuffer(fbb, mloc);

However, I can't find any method named FinishDocBuffer. The generated Doc class only has one method named Verify() in addition to getters. The generated DocBuilder class only has one method named Finish(). And there's only one function named CreateDoc() defined outside of those two classes.

Did I do something wrong, or should the official doc be updated?

FYI, I'm using latest flatbuffers code cloned from the git repo.

Update:
I found the [example code](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/samples/sample_binary.cpp) didn't call any Finish*Buffer() method either.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason. I need to add this line to my doc.fbs file:

> root_type Doc;